# Is using the phrase 'That being said' acceptable in an academic paper for science?

Tags: phrases, academic-writing

I'm currently writing an academic paper on radioactivity, and I included the following sentence in one of my paragraphs:

> That being said, it is also our (the community’s) responsibility to uphold the positive reputation of radioactivity and follow all recommended safety precautions.

I'm wondering if the phrase 'That being said' is acceptable. Should I keep the phrase or remove it from the sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like an odd statement to put into a scientific paper.

Comment: You might also consider "Taking that as the truth", "As such", or "That being true", assuming this is following statements that affirm the reputation of radioactivity.  "That being said" sounds slightly conversational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That being said" is a synonym of

> in spite of that; nevertheless

And also briefly describes concludes the end of a paragraph or point.

There is nothing wrong with using "That being said" at the start of the sentence, especially if before that you made a long paragraph/point on something, radioactivity in this case.

The only thing is, "that being said" is usually used in a speech, not much in a scientific paper.

It **might** be better to use the below (examples):

- all things considered
- clearly
- given these points
- I feel we have no choice but to conclude
- in conclusion
- in drawing to a close
- in general
- in light of this information

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unacceptable about "that being said" in scientific writing.

I have no idea what you mean by "uphold the positive reputation of radioactivity".
That being said, "That being said" might be inappropriate there.